# $f:M \rightarrow M$ is continuous such that $f(f(x))=f(x)$, then $f(M)$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $f:M \rightarrow M$ continuous such that $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for every $x\in M$. Show that $N=f(M)$ is a closed subset of $M$.

What i've done so far:

Let $z\in \overline{f(M)}$. Then $B(z;\epsilon)\cap f(M) \neq \emptyset$ for every $\epsilon>0$. We fix an arbitrary $\epsilon$ and choose $y\in B(z;\epsilon)\cap f(M)$. Therefore $y = f(x)$ for some $x\in M$. Noticing that $B(z;\epsilon)$ is open, we can find an $r>0$ such that $B(y=f(x);r)\subset B(z;\epsilon)$. Since $f$ is continuous, there corresponds a $\delta>0$ such that: $f(B(x,\delta))\subset B(f(x);r)\subset B(z;\epsilon).$

I dunno how to proceed from here to show that $z\in f(M)$.

Any helps, suggestions of different ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_n \in f(M)$ such that $y_n \to y$.

We have that $y_n=f(x_n)$ for $x_n \in M$

Then $f(f(x_n)) \to f(y)$ because $f$ is continuous and

$f(f(x_n))=f(x_n) \to y$

Thus from uniqueness of a limit in metric spaces we have that $y=f(y) \in f(M)$

because $f(M) \subseteq M \Rightarrow f(f(M)) \subseteq f(M)$

Comment: Hah, i wasn't expecting a solution involving sequences, because this exercise appears in a section of my book where sequences are still not defined. But the solution looks great. So i'll just check up some facts about sequences in metric spaces in order to plany justify it myself. Thx

Comment: @math.h...if i have the time i'll try to edit my answer to post a solution without sequences..

Comment: much appreciated.

Comment: @math.h....Indeed you need to learn the sequential characterization of closedness  because it is one of the most usefull theorems in the topology of metric spaces..Sometimes in some books this property is given as a definition but it can be proved also,using properties of closures.

Comment: @math.h are you familiar with sequential continuity?

Comment: Marios, i have only seen sequential continuity in a course of real analysis. But as you wrote down the exercise, it seems that the same results holds (they are really similar)

Comment: @math.h if you know sequential continuity then let $z \in \overline{f(M)}$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ we have that $B(z,\epsilon) \cap f(M) \neq \emptyset$..Thus for $\epsilon=1,\frac{1}{2}....\frac{1}{n}...$ we can find inductively $y_n \in f(M)$ and $y_n \in B(z, \frac{1}{n})$...So we see that  $y_n \to z$ and $y_n \in f(M)$...So you can proceed to prove that $z \in f(M)$ using the sequentialy continuity of $f$..

Comment: Also in the answer i used sequential continuity but in this second answer in the comment i use just the definition of closure infinitely many times to constract a sequence..so i don't use the sequential characterization of closedness..

Comment: thank you very much, sir

Comment: The proof generalizes to all spaces by using  nets.

Comment: Also as @WilliamElliot mentioned it...we have to learn how to use nets(which are the generalization of sequences in arbitrary topological spaces..)me my self i don't know how to use them properly..Nets are very useful in topology and in analysis(especially in functional analysis)